# How to Order only first 20 records in a resultset using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My requirement is to get the List of Diagnosis based on the most used Diagnosis. So, to achieve that I have added one Column named DiagnosisCounter in the tblDiagnosisMst Table of the database which increases by 1 for each Diagnosis the each time user selects it. So, my query is like below:

```
  select DiagnosisID,DiagnosisCode,Name from tblDiagnosisMst 
  where GroupName = 'Common' and RecStatus = 'A' order by DiagnosisCounter desc, 
  Name asc
```

So, this query is helping me to get the list of Diagnosis but in descending order for Diagnosis and then alphabetically for Diagnosis Name. But now my client wants to show only 20 most used Diagnosis name at the top and then all the names should appear in alphabetical order. But unfortunately I am stuck in this point. It would be so appreciative if I get your helpful advice for this problem.

Comment: What database system (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL) and version are you using?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I am using SQL server 2005. Thanks.

Comment: use top 20 in your select statement like  " select top 20 DiagnosisID,DiagnosisCode,Name from tblDiagnosisMst where GroupName = 'Common' and RecStatus = 'A' order by DiagnosisCounter desc, 
  Name asc"

Comment: But selecting Top 20 will only give me Top 20 rows. But I want all the rows only Top 20 will be arranged base on the condition DiagnosisCoundet Desc Because my client wants to see all the list which I am binding with a single Gridview

Comment: Can not be done - you will need to queries then. SQL has no concept of sorting only a part of a set. You may be able to hide that in a very complex sql statement, but I would do that on the client, not in sql.

Comment: @TomTom - would you really describe my answer as "very complex"?

Comment: Yes, compared to the knowledge of the poster. It actually is more complex as it needs to IIRC - there is no need to even had a WITH Ordered clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
;With Ordered as (
  select DiagnosisID,DiagnosisCode,Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DiagnosisCounter desc) as rn
  from tblDiagnosisMst 
  where GroupName = 'Common' and RecStatus = 'A'
)
select * from Ordered
order by CASE WHEN rn <= 20 THEN rn ELSE 21 END, 
  Name asc
```

We use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to assign the numbers 1-x to each of the rows, based on the `diagnosiscounter`. We then use that value for the first `ORDER BY` condition if it's in 1-20, and all other rows sort equally in position `21`. The second condition is then used as a tie-breaker to sort those remaining row by `name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...You have made my day my friend. I am so grateful. It's just working like a charm. Thanks again. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 20
 * FROM tblDiagnosisMst ORDER BY DiagnosisCounter;
```